# Prolog, add list of list together to make one list

Tags: recursion, matrix, prolog, predicate

Hi I need to write a Prolog predicate that will sum the lines of a list of list so given

```
|a,b,c| |j,k,l| |s,t,u|
|d,e,f| |m,n,o| |v,w,x|
|g,h,i|.|p,q,r|,|y,z,?|

/*I want to be able to get back */
|(a+j+s),(b+k+t),(c+l+u)|
|(d+m+v),(e+n+w),(f+o+x)|
|(g+p+y),(h+q+z),(i+r+?)|
```

Im having a hard time because I want to add the head to the head of the tail, and so on but can't figure out away to tell prolog to do that. I can add any one line at a time or even just two matrices but given a list like this I cannot see to get it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your code so far? Also, show how you would like the query to work. And could you use Prolog syntax? Do these represent numbers, or are you looking for symbolic addition as shown?

Comment: You should always prefer to edit the question in response to a comment, if possible. Large code blocks like that are hard to use from the comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog Have a list initialized to zero to use sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391427/prolog-have-a-list-initialized-to-zero-to-use-sum)